# Pandas filter df by date range and condition

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timedelta

I have a dataframe that contains 3 datetime columns

```
              ItemUid   HireStart    DCompleteDate       OffHire
              14055     2021-01-01       2021-12-17      2021-01-09
              14065     2021-08-12       2021-12-17      2021-11-17
              14534     2018-12-21             NaT             NaT
              11639           NaT              NaT             NaT
              43268     2020-09-07       2020-09-03      2020-11-03
              36723     2021-01-03             Nat       2021-01-10
```

I am trying to return a dataframe that returns the items that were on hire between a user inputted date range.

Ie: if the user inputs: start date = '2021-01-02' & end date = '2021-01-08' the expected result would be:

```
          ItemUid   HireStart    DCompleteDate       OffHire
          14055     2021-01-01       2021-01-23      2021-01-09
          14534     2018-12-21             NaT             NaT
          36723     2021-01-03             Nat       2021-01-10
```

**My code :)**

```
def date_range(df):
    start_date = input("Enter start date dd/mm/yyyy: ")
    end_date = input("Enter end date dd/mm/yyyy: ")

    df = df[(df['OffHire'] <= end_date) & 
             ((df['HireStart'].notna()) | (df['HireStart'] >= start_date))]
    
    return df

result = df_hire.apply(date_range, axis=1)
```

This is currently getting an error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-60-6d4d17020cba> in <module>()
      9     return df
     10 
---> 11 result = df_hire.apply(date_range, axis=1)

4 frames
<ipython-input-60-6d4d17020cba> in date_range(df)
      3     end_date = input("Enter end date dd/mm/yyyy: ")
      4 
----> 5     df = df[(df['OffHire'] <= end_date) & 
      6              ((df['HireStart'].notna()) | (df['HireStart'] >= start_date))]
      7 

TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'Timestamp' and 'str'
```

I could probably fix the error, however the implementation of how to apply the function has me stuck!

**Any help would be greatly appreciated and would be another lesson for me!**

Thanks in advance

Comment: think about how you could convert `end_date` to a Timestamp, possibly.

Comment: You use `Actual Off Hire` and `'ErCompleteDate` in your function but your `df` doesn't have these columns. Also your expected output doesn't match your date range. How did the first row of your output get a "DCompleteDate" of "2021-01-23" when the original row was "2021-12-17"? And why is the second row included when the "HireStart" is before the input start_date?

Comment: Yes Sorry, I amended the col names for clarity but forgot to change the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you want something like this:

```
#convert the date columns to datetime
df["HireStart"] = pd.to_datetime(df["HireStart"])
df["DCompleteDate"] = pd.to_datetime(df["DCompleteDate"])
df["OffHire"] = pd.to_datetime(df["OffHire"])

#convert inputs to datetime
start_date = pd.to_datetime(start_date, format="%d/%m/%Y")
end_date = pd.to_datetime(end_date, format="%d/%m/%Y")

#select the required rows
output = df[df["HireStart"].le(end_date)&df["DCompleteDate"].fillna(start_date).ge(start_date)]
```

Comment: you can use `.between(start, stop)` for datetime columns

Comment: @PaulH - If the operations were on the same column, yes. These are on two different columns.

Comment: getting AttributeError: 'Timestamp' object has no attribute 'le'

Comment: Which means you're using this on a single Timestamp and not a whole column as I've done.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way is to use `HireStart` as index and exploit pandas slicing for datetime index. Something like:

```
df.set_index('HireStart')['2021-01-02':'2021-01-08']
```